# Missing cache file errors?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have ran into a frustrating issue in my project that has resulted in errors appearing in the event log every ~30 seconds. Here is the type of thing I'm seeing -

> FileNotFoundException: /Users/User/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio1.5/caches/names.dat.keystream.len
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> FileNotFoundException: /Users/User/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio1.5/index/filenameindex/FilenameIndex_inputs_i.len
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> FileNotFoundException: /Users/User/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio1.5/index/stubs/java.class.fqn/java.class.fqn_i.len
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> FileNotFoundException: /Users/User/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio1.5/caches/contentHashes.dat.keystream.len
>   (No such file or directory)

I've tried to rebuild the project as suggested in other similar questions, however that made no difference.

I'm not sure if this could possibly be the cause of the issue, but as I was running very low on space I used an app called 'Disk Diag' to clear up some free space, and the issue seemed to occur not long after that, so I'm not sure if it's deleted some files.

Anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I've just checked to see if the files actually exist, and some do, and others don't.

For example, `/Users/User/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio1.5/index/filenameindex/FilenameIndex_inputs_i.len` does exist, however the entire `/Users/User/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio1.5/caches/` directory is missing.

Comment: Have you checked to see if those file paths actually do exist? Particularly up to `/Users/User/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio1.5/`?

Comment: I've added an edit with an answer to your comment.

Comment: It looks like after the rebuild I'm no longer getting issues with the index directory, just the caches one.

Comment: Try creating the `caches` folder manually and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Perfect! I hadn't expected it to be that simple, hence why I hadn't tried that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This problem also happens in Android Studio 2.1. But it locks up the IDE until it's manually restarted: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211761

Answer (score 10):

Just invalidate cache and restart android studio.

On mac's 
File -> Inavlidate caches/restart (select this option)

You can build your app or create apks using gradle after this.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the caches folder manually
I did it and resolves issue